# Regex for markdown table

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So I have a pretty tricky regex I can't wrap my head around how to make. I want to match a whole markdown table block, ie from the first rows, either from the start of the string or from two linebreaks and then every line containing | until another two linebreaks or end. For example:

> **Premise:** 10 years after the end of Precrime in Washington DC one of the three PreCogs attempts to lead on a normal life while still
>   suffering from visions of the future. Will they be able to hold it
>   together or mentally breakdown and give up?
>
> **Subreddit:** | **Network:** | **Premiere date:** | **Airing:** | **Metacritic:**
>
> :--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:
>
> **/r/MinorityReport** | [Fox](http://www.fox.com/minority-report) | September 21, 2015 | Monday 9:00 PM EST |
>   [52/100](http://www.metacritic.com/tv/minority-report-2015)
>
> yadayadayada

Where it would skip the top part and the yada yada part. This is what i got right now. I know there's some markdown regex's answers already but couldn't find one relating to this exact scenario. Would be immensely appreciated,thanks

Comment: Did you try positive look behind and look ahead assertions? [`(?s)(?<=(\r?\n){2}|^)((?-s).*?\|.*|\r?\n)*(?=(\r?\n){2}|$)`](http://goo.gl/lIz90M)

Comment: @Verarind That seems to work great, thanks! if you submit it as an answer I can mark it answered

Comment: @Verarind I noticed however that .Net weirdly also seem to match on this string:  [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4450826/)\r\n\r\n\r\n, even though the online regex tester does not

Comment: I could not believe that because the regex enforces \|.      I'll test it. Oh I see it. I'll fix it.

Comment: The online regex does also match - but it matches an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not enough information about markdown tables but based on your description I wrote this regex:

[`(?<=(\r?\n){2}|^)([^\r\n]*\|[^\r\n]*(\r?\n)?)+(?=(\r?\n){2}|$)`](http://goo.gl/OZ9Xuw)

This should work now (hopefully).

I copied your table into [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) but it contains a double newline after each line. I've to change it because you wrote that this is the end marker of the table. (I wasted a litle time to find this problem.)

Comment: Much appreciated, I didn't actually know about lookbehinds. Thanks for your time and effort!